# Strange behavior of RandomVariate and PascalDistribution

Tags: bugs, random, distributions

Observe:

```
sr = 666;

d = PascalDistribution[1, 1/50];
od = OrderDistribution[{d, 10}, 1];

Column[{Mean[od] // N,
  SeedRandom[sr];
  Dimensions@(t1 = RandomVariate[d, {1000, 10}]),
  SeedRandom[sr];
  Dimensions@(t2 = Table[RandomVariate[d, 10], 1000]),
  SeedRandom[sr];
  Dimensions@(t3 = Partition[RandomVariate[d, 10000], 10]),
  SeedRandom[sr];
  Dimensions@(t4 = 
     ArrayReshape[Table[RandomVariate[d, 100], 100], {1000, 10}]),
  Min /@ t1 // Mean // N,
  Min /@ t2 // Mean // N,
  Min /@ t3 // Mean // N,
  Min /@ t4 // Mean // N}]
```

> 5.46666
>
> {1000,10}
>
> {1000,10}
>
> {1000,10}
>
> {1000,10}
>
> 5.463
>
> 6.484
>
> 5.463
>
> 5.463

The results from `Min/@t...//Mean//N` should be the same for all four cases.

Note the result (using the 666 seed) of 6.484 for the `t2` case. This is consistently wacky (~+1 from actual expectation shown by the mean of the order distribution).

Changing the inner cardinality for the `t4` case to anything 80 or above (e.g. `ArrayReshape[Table[RandomVariate[d, 80], 125], {1000, 10}]`keeps it consistent, but lowering it to say 50 in the RV generation results in also off-kilter results.

I'd venture there is some kind of heuristic switching of methods going on based on requested number of samples, and perhaps a bug in the low-count algorithm.

On 10.3 Windows, same results on 9.X Windows.

I'd appreciate verification (and explanation if I've pulled a DOH and there's a reason for this behavior).

Comment: Verified on 10.4.1, OS X

Comment: You should report this to Wolfram. There is a build in switch. I'm using version 10.4.1 on Win 10.

Comment: Another indication that this is a real bug is the fact that for `NegativeBinomialDistribution` `RandomVariate` is implemented in a very similar way (calling the same ``Statistics`BinomialDistributionsDump`*`` functions), but doesn't produce inconsistent results (at least not for the same parameters used in this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an extended comment:  Rather than a consistent shift for the values in the minimum values for `t2`, it appears that the distribution is completely different than for `t1`, `t3`, and `t4`.  Here's a figure showing that:

```
h[x_, label_] := Histogram[Min /@ x, {1}, "PDF", PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 0.20}}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[label, Bold, Larger]]
GraphicsGrid[{{h[t1, "t1"], h[t2, "t2"]}, {h[t3, "t3"], h[t4, "t4"]}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Histograms]

Comment: Yes, the number I referred to was just for the expectation, histograms make it clear why. Seems like a bug to me, adding that tag, will have assistant report to WRI if they have time.

Answer (score 2):

In the `t1` case

```
Random`DistributionVector[PascalDistribution[1, 1/50], 10000, ∞]
```

is evaluated and in the `t2` case

```
Random`DistributionVector[PascalDistribution[1, 1/50], 10, ∞]
```

The definition of this function contains a `Which` statement. Its first test is `True` for `10000` and `False` for `10`. Its second test (there are only two) is `True`.

For your parameters for the `PascalDistribution` the switch happens between 62 and 63.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug.

Histogram shows result of 100K RV on `PascalDistribution[1,1/50]` for 100k batch using `RandomVariate[...,100000]` (blue) and generating a table of 100k single calls (default chicken-poop-and-mud jaundice beige):

[image]

Thanks to Karsten for verification and Jim for histogram idea.

Comment: I had to smile at the choice of adjectives. :)